# Are there cultures without knowledge of how babies are made?

Tags: anthropology

I know that there are many cases of cultures having whacky ideas of how exactly babies are made, however in most of these cases they still link the creation of babies to having sex (however weird the link may be). My question is the following:

**Is there any strong evidence of historical (or current) cultures, in which the link between sex and the creation of babies was not understood in the slightest?**

If not, I would accept an answer that comes the closest. Thank you.

*(I apologize if this is the wrong stack exchange, I tried looking for what I deemed the most fitting)*

Comment: Here in Switzerland my grandparents didn't know and had to figure out by themselves in the 1950s. They were told babies were made by kissing on the mouth. Thankfully the mentalities changed in the 1960s,

Comment: I did read that the [Venus figurines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_figurines) are examples of  cult to the women and fertility, and that in ancient (paleo and neolithic cultures) the lack of knowledge about the process of birth made women to be considered almost sacred (remember, not all couples that have sex get to have children, so the correlation is not that easy to see). Of course, that is just one of several possible explanations.

Comment: @Bregalad Thanks for the story, very interesting. I wonder how widespread the "ignorance" was -- I'm guessing (?) that most people knew, even though sex was a really taboo subject back then.

Comment: @SJuan76 I've heard about the Venus figurines before -- they are quite interesting. The reason why I'm asking the question is exactly for the reason that you mention: the correlation is not that obvious, and may even seem magical. The fact that not all sex leads to pregnancies, and the fact that the baby grows over many months afterwards, makes me suspect that such cultures would've existed (or even exists in the present, perhaps in current hunter-gatherer societies).

Comment: @Eff Well I guess there were rumours circulating among teens, but only after actually doing it they would understand the truth. (This is just an educated guess). Also I suspect that people in the 19th century were more sexually educated than people of the early 20th ironically - I could be wrong, it's just my own supposition that could be completely wrong.

Comment: Any culture undertaking animal husbandry would have a knowledge of the facts of reproduction.  That said my wife tells the story of her then-teenage great grandmother locking her new husband out of their bedroom when she found out what he intended to do to her.  This was in New Orleans at the turn of the 20th century IIRC.

Comment: @AllInOne Good point, agricultural societies would probably know. However, perhaps there could be hunter-gatherer societies.

Comment: If there was such a culture, I doubt it would have survived beyond the lifespan of the founding individual. If that person didn't know how to make babies, there would be no one to carry on his legacy once he dies

Comment: @NSNoob I don't think that's necessarily true. I think our evolved predisposition to have sex would have people engage in it, even without knowledge of the outcomes of having sex.

Comment: @Eff Huh! didn't think of it quite like that. This is actually plausible. A counter argument would be however that the same predisposition also makes us find patterns in stuff occurring around us, how long before someone finds the pattern that prior to every pregnancy, the mother had sex while no woman ever got pregnant without a sexual intercourse? Not very long, If you ask me. Of course that's speculation, not an answer.

Comment: I heard from a doctor that he and other male students were only allowed use of the pool the night before it was to be drained because the high school girls were told by the nuns that one became pregnant by swimming in water in which male (humans) had swum. This was 1950s or maybe 1960s. The point is, the knowledge is not innate; the girls believed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of any group that doesn't make the connection between sex and reproduction but there are/were cultures that don't understand it in its entirety. In particular, there used to be many societies who believed in multiple paternity, where a baby can have multiple fathers if a woman has sex with multiple men. You can find this belief among several Amazon tribes as well as ancient Hawaii.

Edit:

I've been doing some reading and it appears that among one tribe in New Guinea people didn't make the connection between sex and reproduction at all, so families were matrilineal. The people proved this because a man's wife could have a child even when he's been travelling for two years. (Scientific explanation: adultery.) They also understand that reproduction works the same for all animal species and their pigs reproduce even though they castrate all the males. (Scientific explanation: domesticated female pigs mate with wild pigs.)

Comment: This might be more to do with expediency.  It prevents arguments about who is responsible for the child.

Comment: Until fairly recent times, I don't think it could have been proven that babies could *not* have more than one father and it is not that crazy of an idea; in the case of multiple births of course there can be different fathers, at least in, for example, cats. So I wonder if even Western cultures might have held this belief prior to 1900 or 1800. In fact, while this can't happen through conventional fertilization, it can be done artificially right now.

Comment: @Jeff Whether superfetation can happen ina few very rare cases through conventional fertilization in Humans reamins debatable: through conventional fertilization

Comment: Do you have a citation for the second part?

Answer (score 4):

From Robert Graves' *The Greek Myths* :

> Once the relevance of coition to child-bearing had been admitted - an account of this tuning-point in religion appears in the Hittite myth of Appu (H.G. Guterbock: *Kamarbi*, 1946) - man's religious status gradually improved, and winds or rivers were no longer given credit for impregnating women.

So this view identifies a date of between 1600BCE and about 1200BCE.

Interestingly, Graves notes that this change in outlook coincides with the change from matrilineal societies to patrilineal societies.

---

In the [Myth of Appu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appu_(Hurrian)), poor old Appu is busy sacrificing sheep to the gods when, according to the wikipedia article -

> The sun-god appears and advises him to get drunk and then have sex with his wife.